# Best strategy you know of for winning at texas hold'em

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, betting-strategy, strategy, poker-strategy

I host a local texas hold'em games at my house every friday. However, I always lose money while my friends are usually win some/lose some. How can I increase my odds of winning? I don't know much about strategies. I just fold when I have low numbers and when they are far apart in value and unpaired. Haven't tried bluffing too much, although I know people really do this well. Please any strategy you know that will help me please explain I am sick of losing!

Thank You

Comment: I closed your question because it's way too broad. I mean, how to win at Texas Hold'em is the subject of hundreds and hundreds of books, way beyond something that someone might be able to answer here. My advice is to study the game, buy some good books about, watch it on TV, on YouTube, on PokerStars.tv, see how people play, study it, practice it for a while. I'll promise, you'll get better at it. As for your question: if you have something more specific to ask, then please edit and vote it for re-opening :) .

Comment: "Now, like all great plans, my strategy is so simple an idiot could have devised it." - Captain Zapp Brannigan. Lose less than you win :))) What @raduMurzea said is a great start. Invest into books by poker pros too. It will help. Remember, Poker is not chess, you can never be 100% certain. That means, there's no winning strategy for every game.